# Angular Overlay is hidden under stickied header

Tags: html, css, angular

I want a mat-spinner overlaid onto my app while loading. I am using an overlay component with Overlay from @angular/cdk/overlay.
 The problem is part of the spinner that gets overlaid ends up hidden under a table header. It overlays on top of everything else on the page but the table header seems to come to the front and obstruct the overlay.
 If I change the `position` property of the table header in the .css file from `sticky` to `fixed` then this problem goes away and the overlay behaves as I want it to but then the table header obviously does not behave correctly.
 I want the table header to remain behaving like it's stickied but I also need the overlay to overlay the whole page and not be obstructed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If spinner is under the table header then you need to give padding-bottom to table header same as table header height . this is what i understand from your post .. hope it will help your problem otherwise you can come again with more detailed question with screenshot place in question.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add a screenshot as I do not own the application and I do not  have permission. The spinner is not below the header but is under the header, so part of the spinner is being obstructed as if hidden behind the table header.

Comment: Well in that case try giving margin to spinner from the side of obstruction.